Pandoc from Markdown to PDF: Font size is affected by linestrech?
I was able to make the font size 13pt for the document class article when converting md document to PDF through pandoc by adding the following YAML metadata in front of the document:
---
documentclass: article
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes: |
  \renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{13pt}{15pt}\selectfont}
  \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont}
...

Somehow this worked, although I put fontsize: 12pt (without that command, my document comes to have the smaller font size for some reason). But once I put the linestrech: 2, the fontsize becomes to be 12 pt like before. Like:
---
documentclass: article
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 2
header-includes: |
  \renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{13pt}{15pt}\selectfont}
  \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont}
...

This makes my document to have 12 fontsize for the main body once again. How can I keep using 13 fontsize with the linestrech: 2?

I cannot reproduce the problem. Can you please show a minimal working example at least of a test document and also the exact pandoc usage. Better would IMHO be to show a MWE of the generated LaTeX code. BTW: Your redefinition of \normalsize and \footnotesize is a little bit simple, maybe too simple. See, e.g., size12.clo for the original definitions. Moreover, IMHO lengths like \headheight, \topskip, \textheight etc. should also be adapted, e.g., to avoid possible overfull \vbox warnings and vertical stretching on every page.

The article class does not have an  option for 13pt. therefore, if you set the  fontsize: to 13pt or to 237pt the result is the same:: the default font size (10pt).
Maybe you can consider to simply switcn  to scrartcl:
MWE (Quarto flavor, it must have the extension .qmd):
---
documentclass: scrartcl
format: pdf
fontsize: 13pt
---

You should see that normal size is 13pt, the footnotes  have 10.83347pt and if you are too picky with the exact font sizes, well, use \changefontsizes{11pt}
To test that the document is using really this font sizes type this in the body of the document:
foo = \makeatletter\f@size pt

\footnotesize  

foo = \f@size pt

\changefontsizes{11pt}

foo = \f@size pt

